# React js not displaying counter and buttons properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to implement component life cycle in react js, I'm getting different errors if I fix each issue.

I'm adding my code snippet here

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component} from 'react'; 
import Counter from './Counter'
import './App.css';
//import Counter from './Counter'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class App extends React.Component{

 constructor (props){
   super(props);
   this.state={
     mount:true
   }
this.mountCounter=()=> this.setState({mount:true})
this.unmountCounter=()=> this.setState({mount:false})


 }

 render(){
  return <div>
<button onClick={this.mountCounter}disabled={this.state.mount}>Mount Counter</button>
<button onClick={this.unmountCounter}disabled={this.state.mount}>unMount Counter</button>

<counter/>



    </div>
  
}
}
export default App;
//ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

Error

[image]

**Counter.js**

```
import React from 'react'; 

import './App.css';
export default class Counter extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            counter:0
        }
    

this.increment=()=>this.setState({counter:this.state.counter+1 })
this.decrement=()=>this.setState({counter:this.state.counter-1})
}

    componentDidMount(){
    console.log('component did mount')
    console.log('-------------------')
    }

    render(){

        console.log('render')
        return <div>
            <button onClick={this.increment}></button>
            <button onClick={this.decrement}></button>
            <div className="counter">

                counter:{this.state.counter}
                </div>
                </div >
    }
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState,snapshot){
     console.log('componentDidUpdate')
     console.log('------')
 
}
componentWillUnmount(){

    console.log('component will unmount ')
}
}
```

I'm stuck with this part. I reviewed stackoverflow and try different but nothing works. In some cases its showing like `counter.js` is not found, actually by file name is `Counter.js`. I added the DOM and tried still no output. Any idea might be helpful for me.

I'm attaching the video link I'm referencing [youtube video](https://youtu.be/m_mtV4YaI8c)

[My ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jdjq.png)[Desired ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYBXC.jpg)

Comment: Typo? `class App extends React.Component() {...` isn't a function, it should be `class App extends React.Component {...`. You should probably just define your callbacks normally in the class body.

Comment: What did you search on stackoverflow?

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for ur help.  But when i did it its not working properly. im attaching the screen shot above. please check.

Answer (score 1):

`<counter/>` isn't a defined component. You import a `Counter` component though.

You should be mounting and rendering `Counter`.

```
{this.state.mount && <Counter />}
```

Other change is to not disable both mount and unmount buttons together. Alternate the conditions in which they are disabled.

```
<button onClick={this.mountCounter} disabled={this.state.mount}>
  Mount Counter
</button>
<button onClick={this.unmountCounter} disabled={!this.state.mount}>
  unMount Counter
</button>
```

Full code:

```
import React from "react";

class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    };

    this.increment = () => this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });
    this.decrement = () => this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter - 1 });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("component did mount");
    console.log("-------------------");
  }

  render() {
    console.log("render");
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
        <div className="counter">counter:{this.state.counter}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    console.log("componentDidUpdate");
    console.log("------");
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("component will unmount ");
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mount: true
    };
    this.mountCounter = () => this.setState({ mount: true });
    this.unmountCounter = () => this.setState({ mount: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.mountCounter} disabled={this.state.mount}>
          Mount Counter
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.unmountCounter} disabled={!this.state.mount}>
          unMount Counter
        </button>

        {this.state.mount && <Counter />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit react-js-not-displaying-counter-and-buttons-properly]

Comment: im able to run it on sandbox but its not displaying anything on Vs Code

Comment: @VISHNUPRASADPM Can you explain a bit more about it "not displaying anything on VsCode"? VsCode is an IDE, not a web environment. It's all pretty simple code and works as expected in the sandbox.